# Can I install BackTrack5 Near Ubuntu 11.04 In One External Hard(seagate)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is this possible to install BackTrack5 Near Ubuntu 11.04 In One External Hard(seagate)?

If it is how can I do it ?